# Может ли приложения видеть альбом "Люди" в фото

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

apple автоматически видит людей на фото и сортирует в альбомы в фотопленке. Как я могу достать эти альбомы и фотографии через код?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, такой возможности до сих пор нет. Есть открытый radar:

https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4952697128091648

Может по нему будет какое решение, а может когда-нибудь представят новое `amazing` решение.

Comment: спасибо, так долго искал решение, хоть ясность появилось)